# JQuery Autocomplete array of objects

Tags: json, jsp, spring-mvc, response, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using Spring MVC and try to send an Array of Objects from my controller to use int the JQuery autocomplete. I have managed to do so with an Array `List<String>`. But I can't get it to work with an Array of objects. I need label and value to be different strings in the JQuery autocomplete.

I want to do the following, According to the Autocomplete JQuery UI:

```
[ { label: "Label1", value: "Value1" }, ... ]
```

I have managed to get it working within the JS

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"label":"Label1","value":"Value1"},{"label":"Label2","value":"Value2"}]');
```

But when I create it in my controller i can't send it as an string to the autocomplete (Due to the success in the autocomplete will not trigger and response(data) will not run). So i try creating something as below.

```
    @RequestMapping(params = {"type=itemType"})
public @ResponseBody List<DataObject> returnItemType(@RequestParam("itemType") String itemType) {
    List<DataObject> objList = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
    objList.add(new DataObject("Label1", "Value1"));
    objList.add(new DataObject("Label2", "Value2"));
    return objList;
}

  private static class DataObject {
    private String label;
    private String value;

    public DataObject(String label, String value) {
      this.label = label;
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "label = " +label+ ", value = " +value;
    }
  }
```

If i add Gson `return gson.toJson(objList);`

The JSON looks good in firebug. But then the success in the autocomplete will not run and `response(data)` will not run either cause of the string from the Gson.

The JS for the autocomplete

```
        $(function() {
    $("#itemType").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:         "autocomplete.do",   
                    dataType:    "json",
                    cache:       true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { 
                        "type"   : "itemType",
                        "itemType" : $("#itemType").val()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }

                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {  
                $("#itemType").val(ui.item.value); 
                $("#orderItemFilterForm").submit(); 
            },  
            minLength: 0
    });
    $('#itemType').click(function(){ 
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).data("autocomplete").search($(this).val()); 
    });         
});
```

Any suggestions?